# Serving Node.JS app on a existing server running page on port 80

Tags: virtualhost, node.js

I have a server at www.example.com running a PHP-made webpage served by Apache, this page is listening to port 80.

Now I want to serve my Node.JS on the domain www.example2.com. Both pages should be on the same server, the Node.JS app should be running on port 3000. **How do I achieve this?**

From other answers and blog posts (like this one: http://garr.me/blog/running-node-js-and-apache-together-using-mod_proxy/) I have learnt that I can create a ReverseProxy to redirect www.example.com/app to my app, however this is not the intended behavior. What I want is this new domain www.example2.com to go the server's ip address at port 3000.

*Side question: This question might sound stupid but, can't I redirect the whole domain to the server's IP address at port 3000 from the domain name configuration at GoDaddy/Route53???*

Thanks.

Comment: Create new virtual host and configure mod_proxy to pass all requests to node

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it. The page on the original question gives a good advice however it doesn't seems complete. To achieve this configuration do the following:

-Locate the file httpd.conf on your Apache folders (usually on apache2/conf).

-Add the following lines to the end:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName example2.com
  ServerAlias www.example2.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

-Change the placeholder "example2" for your actual domain name (example2 is the domain name on the original question)

-Restart apache.

Note that you might want to tidy the code a little bit by moving the LoadModule lines to where the modules are actually loaded.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to serve my Node.JS on the domain www.example2.com. Both pages should be on the same server, the Node.JS app should be running on port 3000. How do I achieve this?

There are two steps.

1. You need to create a virtual host in apache listening on IP:3000 and responding to requests for example2.com
2. You need mod_proxy running to take requests for example2.com on port 80 and push them to IP:3000 where the virtual host is listening.

> can't I redirect the whole domain to the server's IP address at port 3000 from the domain name configuration at GoDaddy/Route53???

No. You are not familiar with the various network layers, including where DNS, TCP, IP, and everything in between fits into place. Might I suggest [reading a little book no the topic. Twice.](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565925724.do) It will hold you on good stead. =)

Comment: Thanks. I already solved it by playing a little with the httpd.conf. If you have some pieces of code it would be great to enrich the steps 1 and 2 to have a clearer view on how to achieve that. I'm still not sure that the way that I found (posted now as an answer) is the best answer...